# jquery scrollTop(x) is not scrolling to target when x is big

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, position, scrolltop

I have an issue with .scrollTop()

I have a page that stores the current scrollTop() position in session when unloading.
My goal is that when I come back to this page, the page scrolls until the last scrollTop position I had on it.

My JS code is simple :

```
console.log('=>'+parseInt(scrollto)+' '+parseInt($(window).scrollTop())); 
$(window).scrollTop(scrollto);
console.log('=>'+parseInt(scrollto)+' '+parseInt($(window).scrollTop()));
```

Result in my browser's console :

```
=> 2500 0
=> 2500 2500
```

Ok, my page is scrolled at the exact last postion.

The issue comes with big values of scrollto variable.
This is what I've got in console :

```
=> 12352 0
=> 12352 7683
```

I don't get why it is not scrolling at the requested position

I've even tried this :

```
var max_times= 10;

for(var i=0;i<max_times;i++){
console.log('=>'+parseInt(scrollto)+' '+parseInt($(window).scrollTop()));
if (parseInt(scrollto) > parseInt($(window).scrollTop())) 
    $(window).scrollTop(scrollto);
}
```

And result :

```
=> 13450 0
=> 13450 7985
=> 13450 7985
=> 13450 7985
...
=> 13450 7985
```

Other info :

- I have the same result on Chrome and Safari.
- The page I'm talking about contains a lot of images so it takes some
  time to be fully loaded.

I would really appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Comment: Do the images have their height set? Or does the total height of the page grow as images are loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.

I've found a solution that works.

Thanks for your hints guys, the total height of the page had to be involved.

What I've done is that :

```
var timer = setInterval(function(){
    if ((parseInt(scrollto) > parseInt($(window).scrollTop())) && (parseInt($(document).height())>parseInt(scrollto))){
       $(window).scrollTop(scrollto);
       if ($(window).scrollTop()>=scrollto)
           clearInterval(timer);    
    }
},500);

setTimeout(function(){clearInterval(timer);},10000);
```

I set a interval that checks if the total height of the page is enough to scroll to the requested position each 500ms. If it's the case, it scrolls. If the position is OK, then we clear the interval.

If none of this works, the interval is cleared after 10s.

Thanks again for helping me out with this !

Answer (score 0):

@lalibi has a good point in asking if the images have a height set, if you are asking to scroll to 13450 but at the current time the page height is less than 13450px then something is not going to work correctly. If you try setting a timeout to the scrollTop to when all the images have loaded, does it still fail? If you notice that it doesn't then you will have to either load the images in a way where once all is loaded then execute the scrollTop or set the images height so that page knows exactly how tall it is.